# Displaying Invalid user name or password using MVC Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC validation to check if use name and password exit in database or not. `ModelState.IsValid` is true always even when I did not find any matching user.

```
if (objModel != null)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && Membership.ValidateUser(objUsersModel.UserName, objUsersModel.Password))
    {
        Profile.Initialize(objUsersModel.UserName.Trim(), true);
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(objUsersModel.UserName, false);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

How can I set this to false and set the values for error message in mvc view. Here is my MVC view .

```
<form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">User Name </label>
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { maxlength = 50, @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.UserName)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { maxlength = 50, @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Password)
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <label class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" class="uniform" value=""> Remember me</label>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You need add a `ModelState` error if `ValidateUser()` returns `false` and the return the view.

Comment: how can I set modelState error if i did not found any match

Comment: `ModelState.AddModelError(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `ModelState` error and return the view if the user name and password are not valid

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
  return View(yourModel);
}
if (!Membership.ValidateUser(objUsersModel.UserName, objUsersModel.Password)
{
  ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The user name or password is incorrect");
  return View(yourModel);
}
....
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

and in the view, include

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

to display the message